# Getting mediacontroller issue in videoview for landscape mode

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-videoview

Getting media controller issue in videoview for landscape mode when turned to landscape mode

AndroidView(
modifier = Modifier
.fillMaxWidth(1f)
.fillMaxHeight(1f),

//                    .fillMaxSize(1f),
factory = { context ->

```
                        videoView
                            .apply {

                                setVideoURI(videoUri)

                                setOnPreparedListener {
                                    mediaPlayer = it
                                    seekTo(100)
                                    isShowLoader = false
                                    it.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener { mp, width, height ->
                                        mediaPlayer = it
                                        val mediaController = MediaController(context)
                                        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)
                                        setMediaController(mediaController)
                                    }
                                }

                                if(mediaPlayer != null){
                                    mediaPlayer?.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener{mp, width, height ->
                                        val mediaController = MediaController(context)
                                        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)
                                        mediaController.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                        setMediaController(mediaController)
                                    }
                                }


                                setOnInfoListener { mediaPlayer, i, i2 ->
                                    if(i == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START){
                                        isShowLoader = false
                                    }else if(i == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START){
                                        isShowLoader = true
                                    } else if(i == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END){
                                        isShowLoader = false
                                    }
                                    false
                                }
                                setOnCompletionListener {
                                    if (!messageData?.isViewed!! && !isViewedUpdated) {
                                        isViewedUpdated = true
                                        trackUserMessage()
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                    })
```